# Scipy's 1d numerical integration on a multi-dimensional grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization

In python I want to perform a one dimensional integration of a complicated function which does not have an analytical antiderivative and which not only depends on the integration variable, but also on some parameters.

A very simple example of what I want to integrate is this:

```
def f(t, x):
    return -(x-t)**2
```

I want to integrate the function with respect to `t`, but for many different `x`'s.
Of course I can right an explicit loop like this

```
for i, x in enumerate(x_array):
    F(i) = quad(f, 0, 3, args=(x,))
```

But this takes a long time. Instead I want to calculate the integral for all parameters in an implicit loop:

```
F = quad(f, 0, 3, args=(x_array,))
```

This gives me a TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.
From the message I guessed that it is not straightforward to do this with an implicit loop. I thought this would be quite a common problem, but I did not find anything that would have helped me.

In case it matters, actually I want to perform these integrations over multiple parameters, each being an array:

```
def f(t, x, y, z):
    return -(x-t)**2 - y**2 - z**2
F = quad(f, 0, 3, args=(x_array, y_array, z_array))
```

Comment: Can you find the integral analytically? If so, you may be able to use sympy

Comment: @Bensciens: I just clarified that the function most likely does not have an analytical antiderivative.

Comment: Do you need the high, adaptive precision of quad, or would fixed-point integration be acceptable?

Comment: @Jsl: Of course, high precision is desirable, but I could test the fast implementation of the fixed-point integration with the slow implementation of the quad function. Do you know of any good alternatives to scipy's integration functions, which can also be called in a way I described in my question?

Comment: How well/fast ``quad()`` works strongly depends on the characteristics of your integrand. I am also not sure if an implicit loop would bring you considerable time gains. Besides ``quad()``, many approaches exist on how to numerically integrate functions: One is to approximate the integrand by Taylor, Fourier or other suited series. Could you post your integrand (it's not ``-(x-t)**2 - y**2 - z**2``, is it?).

Comment: @Dietrich: You are right, the integrand is considerably more complicated. It consists of several rational functions (including square roots of these) and exponential functions all being multiplied. The integration domain does not contain any singularities.
But I am not interessted in approximating the integrand in order to integrate it numerically. I found an approximation to calculate the integral. Now I want to compare this to a (fast) numerical solution of the exact integrand.